# How to get mouse and keyboard events, masked by PopUpManager

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am implementing an application timeout feature (flex4).  What I am finding is that mouse and keyboard events, which I have listened to with :

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resetLastActivity);
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, resetLastActivity);
```

are being masked by the existence of any popup windows.  The code is in a component, in the constructor. The component is added to the main application in the  block.

How can I get these system generated events to not get stopped by PopUpManager display objects?

Thanks!

Comment: That's the issue I was facing as well. For the time being, I am keeping track of all the popup's in a collection and adding eventlisteners on them for timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try listening on the [Stage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) instead of the topLevelApplication.  access the stage using the [stage property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#stage) on the topLevelApplication

I think topLevelApplication formally returns an object, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application).stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resetLastActivity);
(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application).stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, resetLastActivity);
```

---

Update:

Keep in mind that the stage is not set in the topLevelApplication until that component's creationComplete event is fired.  If you are adding event listeners to the stage in a non UI class; you have to make sure this is not done until creationComplete fires in the topLevelApplication.

To do this, add an event listener to the topLevelApplication's creationComplete method in the constructor.

```
(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationCompete);
```

If this is an MXML UIComponent, you can add that code in a preinitialize event handler instead of a constructor.

Then this would be the creation complete handler:

```
public function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void{
    (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application).stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resetLastActivity);
    (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application).stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, resetLastActivity);
}
```

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property Application. -stage .. just adding .stage , without doing the 'casting' also doesn't work...it compiles, but runtime crashes.

Comment: @reidLinden When are you adding the listener?  Stage won't be defined until creationComplete is executed.

Comment: my code is in a component, in the constructor.  The component is added to the main application in the <fx:Declarations/> block

Comment: @reidLinden you'll have to rework where you add those event listeners.  IF it is a UIComponent, add those event listeners in a creationComplete handler not the constructor.  If not; then listen for the topLevelApplication's creationComplete event and add the stage event listeners in that handler.

Comment: Flextras...why don't you add another answer with that suggestion...it worked perfectly, but I don't want to select THIS thread as the answer.

Comment: @reidLinden I modified this answer to include some extra info detaling what we discussed in the comments.  Does that suffice?

Comment: I can live with that :D   Thanks Flextras, as always!

Answer (score 1):

This works more elegantly without bothering creationComplete.

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resetSessionTimer);
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, resetSessionTimer);
```